# How to tokenize and transform a c-string using regex and boost transform iterators?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-iterators

I try to tokenize a c-string with semicolon separated digits and store them in a vector. This is my simplified approach

```
auto string = "1;2;3;4";
const std::regex separator {";"};
std::cregex_token_iterator t_begin{string, string + strlen(string), separator, -1};
std::cregex_token_iterator t_end{};
auto begin = boost::make_transform_iterator(t_begin, atoi);
auto end = boost::make_transform_iterator(t_end, atoi);
std::vector<int> result{begin, end};
```

I get the error message:

```
error: no type named 'type' in 'boost::mpl::eval_if<boost::is_same<boost::iterators::use_default, boost::iterators::use_default>, boost::result_of<const int(std::sub_match<const char*>&)>, boost::mpl::identity<boost::iterator::use_default> >::f_{aka struct boost::result_of<const int(const std::sub_match<const char*>&)>}'
typedef typename f_::type type;
```

which I don't understand.

Comment: is that strlen() taking 2 parameters something that you've defined?

Comment: did you mean t_begin/t_end in your boost::make_transform_iterator calls?

Comment: Yes, because I wrote it on a machine without internet access.

Comment: Please post only real code that you have tested. There's no point in us looking at code that could have any number of additional errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::cregex_token_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator), when dereferenced, returns a [`std::sub_match`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/sub_match) of a corresponding type. In this case, it's a pair of `const char*` pointers, so a possible solution is as follows:

```
auto f = [] (std::csub_match m) { return std::atoi(m.first); };

auto begin = boost::make_transform_iterator(t_begin, f);     
auto end = boost::make_transform_iterator(t_end, f);
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5edfb6b3925c043b)

Comment: @TNA no, the input string is not modified, `m.first` points to the beginning of the match in the original string, while `m.second` points to the end within the original string. e.g., for the first match, `m.second` will point to `;`. but `std::atoi` automatically stops further parsing on a first non-integer character